# Ajax Form Submit is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, form-submit

I have a simple form for feedback as below which uses an image as the submit button instead of the standard HTML submit button. The form appears to submit but the "data:" value is always NULL. What am I doing wrong? Code below.

The FORM:

```
<div id="theResponse" class="ContactForm"></div>
    <label><span class="footer_text_2"> Email</span> </label>
    <br />
    <form name="contact" method="post" action="">
      <input name="txtEmail" type="text" class="contact" id="txtEmail" value="" />
      <span class="footer_text_2"> Message</span>
      <textarea name="txtComment" cols="18" rows="3" class="contact" id="txtComment"></textarea>
      <input name="Id" type="hidden" id="Id"  value="1"/>
      <input name="input" type="image"  id="ContactSubmit" src="images/btn_send.png" width="60" height="22"/>
    </form>
```

The JQUERY CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Bind the click event for the login button
$("#ContactSubmit").bind("click", function(){ });
// The click event for button click
$('#ContactSubmit').click(function() {
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "MyAccount/ProcessContactForm.asp",
            data:  $("#contact").serialize(),
            cache: false,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(responseText){
                $("#theResponse").html(responseText);
            },
        });
    return false;
});
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Remove the last comma after the success function, before closing the Ajax call, otherwise IE will throw an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

Missing `id="contact"` in `form`

```
<form name="contact" method="post" id="contact" action="">
```

---

or Use this with your current `form` html

```
data:  $('form[name="contact"]').serialize(),
```

Comment: i never realized the stupid oversight of id="contact". Worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
data:  $("#contact").serialize(),
```

You are selecting the id.

You should change this line:

```
<form name="contact" method="post" action="">
```

to

```
<form id="contact" method="post" action="">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#contact").serialize()
```

This won't work if you do not set the "id" attribute to you form element.

The rest is ok, should work right :)